# How to find which paths of Firebase Realtime DB consumes the most of the downloads?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Is there a way to analyze firebase realtime database downloads? I want to find out how data download is distributed among different paths of the database.

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/profile

Comment: Thank you very much @FrankvanPuffelen for the quick response. It's a really useful tool.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Database Profile tool can be used for this.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/profile

Just run `firebase database:profile --project production`

It will give you a detailed summary of the database usage within the given period of time.

- Thank you Frank for the answer